# MySQL permutation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One has products and the other has bundles that go with it.  I need to figure out the SQL that allows me to find all the combinations in which I can sell the product with extras.

```
Products

Name   ID
Bench   1

Extra

Name           ID     Parent ID  QTY
undershelf     1        1        1
overshelf      2        1        1
wheels         3        1        1
```

I need and output table that shows all the combination in which I can sell the product:

```
Bench
Bench + undershelf
Bench + undershelf + overshelf
Bench + overshelf
Bench + wheels
bench + wheels + overshelf  and so one.
```

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of `parent-to-child` relationships?  If so, you can `join` the table to itself to get your desired result.  If not, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` to accomplish this.

Comment: @sgeddes Yes, I do have max number of parent-to-child relationship and have no issue  using dynamic sql with php. But I have no clue how the join will give me my desired results.

Comment: Not to be overly pedantic, but you're not interested in permutations like the title suggests, but rather combinations like you mentioned in the question text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every extras can be in the bundle or not, making that a binary property.
A way to visualize the combination is to create a word with a bit for every extra, `1` mean that the extra is in the list, `0` mean the that it is not.
For example `Bench + undershelf + overshelf` is 110 (or 011 if the binary string is read in the opposite order)

Generating every combination of n bit will give every combination of n extras, it will also give every number from `0` to `2^n - 1`.

We can work back from here:
1. generate the list of number from `0` to `2^n - 1`;
2. convert the number to binary, to list the combination of extras
3. match every bit with an extra
4. concatenate the names of the extras in the bundle description.

```
SELECT CONCAT(b.Name
            , COALESCE(CONCAT(' + '
                            , GROUP_CONCAT(x.Name SEPARATOR ' + '))
                     , '')) Combination
FROM   (SELECT p.Name, p.id
                     , LPAD(BIN(u.N + t.N * 10), e.Dim, '0') bitmap
                FROM   Products p
                       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 N UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
                         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
                         UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) u
                       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 N UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
                         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
                         UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t
                       INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) Dim
                                       , `Parent ID` pID
                                   FROM Extra) E ON e.pID = p.ID
                WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < Pow(2, e.Dim)
       ) B
       LEFT  JOIN (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 ID
                        , `Parent ID` pID
                        , Name
                   FROM   Extra
                        , (Select @rownum := 0) r) X
                          ON x.pID = b.ID
                         AND SUBSTRING(b.bitmap, x.ID, 1) = '1'
GROUP BY b.Name, b.bitmap
```

this query will work up to six extras, then it'll need another digit table (one digit every three extras).

**How it Works**

The subquery **`E`** count the number of the extras, this is used in **`C`** to limit the elements generated by the digit tables `u` and `t` (unit and tens) to 2^dim.

The number is converted to binary by `BIN(u.N + t.N * 10)`, then left padded with '0' to the number of elements, generating a combination bitmap.

To use the generated bitmap each extras need a fake id that will match a position in it, that's what the subquery **`X`** is meant for.

The two subqueries are `JOIN`ed by the nth char of the bitmap: if the char is 1 the extra is in the bundle, `LEFT` joined to not loose the product without extras.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any ingenious way of doing this in mysql, but it is very easy in a scripting language. Here in PHP:

```
<?php
$extra = array('undershelf', 'overshelf', 'sheels');
$possible_combinations = pow(2, count($extra));
for ($i = 0; $i < $possible_combinations; $i++) {
    $combo = array('Bench');
    foreach ($extra as $j => $item) {
        if ($i & pow(2, $j)) {
            $combo[] = $item;
        }
    }

    echo implode(' + ', $combo) . "\n";
}
```

prints

```
Bench
Bench + undershelf
Bench + overshelf
Bench + undershelf + overshelf
Bench + sheels
Bench + undershelf + sheels
Bench + overshelf + sheels
Bench + undershelf + overshelf + sheels
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible entirely within MySQL, though not simple.  This example can handle up to 5 "extras", and is easily extensible for more:

```
CREATE TABLE products (name varchar(100), id int primary key);
INSERT INTO products (name, id) VALUES ('Bench', 1);

CREATE TABLE extra (name varchar(100), id int primary key, parent_id int references products.id, qty int);
INSERT INTO extra (name, id, parent_id, qty) VALUES 
  ('undershelf', 1, 1, 1), ('overshelf', 2, 1, 1), ('wheels', 3, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE boolean_values (x boolean);
INSERT INTO boolean_values VALUES (TRUE), (FALSE);

CREATE VIEW product_extras_interim_vw AS
SELECT p.id product_id, p.name product_name, e.id extra_id, e.name extra_name, x
  FROM products p
  JOIN extra e ON (e.parent_id = p.id)
  CROSS JOIN boolean_values;

SELECT DISTINCT a.product_name
, CASE WHEN a.x THEN CONCAT(' + ', a.extra_name) END extra1
    , CASE WHEN b.x THEN CONCAT(' + ', b.extra_name) END extra2
    , CASE WHEN c.x THEN CONCAT(' + ', c.extra_name) END extra3
    , CASE WHEN d.x THEN CONCAT(' + ', d.extra_name) END extra4
    , CASE WHEN e.x THEN CONCAT(' + ', e.extra_name) END extra5
FROM product_extras_interim_vw a
LEFT JOIN product_extras_interim_vw b
  ON ( a.product_id = b.product_id
      AND b.extra_id > a.extra_id
  AND a.x )
LEFT JOIN product_extras_interim_vw c
  ON ( a.product_id = c.product_id
  AND c.extra_id > b.extra_id
      AND b.x )
LEFT JOIN product_extras_interim_vw d
  ON ( a.product_id = d.product_id
      AND d.extra_id > c.extra_id
      AND c.x)
LEFT JOIN product_extras_interim_vw e
  ON ( a.product_id = e.product_id
      AND e.extra_id > d.extra_id
      AND d.x)
ORDER BY product_name, extra1, extra2, extra3, extra4, extra5;
```

Output:

```
Bench
Bench + overshelf
Bench + overshelf + wheels
Bench + undershelf
Bench + undershelf + overshelf
Bench + undershelf + overshelf + wheels
Bench + undershelf + wheels
Bench + wheels
```

Comment: After coming up with this solution in MySQL, as a good exercise, I realize I don't think I'd ever do it entirely in SQL.  Probably best done in a language like PHP or Java.  If you had to do it entirely in a database, maybe using stored procs would be an alternative.

Comment: posted this in SQL Fiddle in case anyone wants to play with the code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a823/1