# Join all SQL row permutations together, including higher-order permutations

Tags: sql, permutation, teradata

I have 3 lines of data like this:-

```
Score | Grp
1     | A
10    | B
100   | C
```

I would like all combinations, much like this:-

```
Score | Grp
1     | A
10    | B
100   | C
11    | A/B
101   | A/C
110   | B/C
111   | A/B/C
```

( In future, there could be more than 3 groups. )

On Teradata, this code gets me much of the way there (`rn` is row number, a sequential integer for each row):-

```
with recursive cte(ev_grp, score, rn, new_grp, new_score) as
 ( select l.ev_grp, l.score, l.rn, ev_grp as new_grp, score as new_score 
   from in_tab as l

   union all

   select inn.ev_grp, inn.score, inn.rn, 
          inn.ev_grp||'/'||cte.ev_grp as new_grp, (inn.score + cte.score) as new_score
   from in_tab as inn  
   join cte
   on inn.rn > cte.rn
 )    
select f.*
from cte f 
order by f.new_score
```

However, the last row - all 3 groups - the results are wrong and I can't think how to solve it.  Any help would be great.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235869/mysql-permutation

Comment: How many groups are you talking about... ? This is a bad road to travel down if you have a few dozen groups.

Comment: It would only be 5-6 groups at most @Rabbit.

Comment: And thanks for the link @juan-carlos-oropeza.  The complicated answers there do strongly suggest the use of a scripting language.

Comment: In that case, if Teradata allows it, you can use a recursive CTE to do this. I know it can be done in MS SQL Server, but I don't have experience in Teradata so I don't know if you can use recursive CTEs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `new_grp` & `new_score` instead of `ev_grp` & `score`. And take care that `new_grp` will not be truncated:

```
with recursive cte(ev_grp, score, rn, new_grp, new_score) as
 ( select l.ev_grp, l.score, l.rn, 
      CAST(ev_grp AS VARCHAR(1000)) as new_grp, -- must be large enough to store all concatenated groups 
      score as new_score 
   from in_tab as l

   union all

   select inn.ev_grp, inn.score, inn.rn, 
          inn.ev_grp||'/'||cte.new_grp as new_grp, (inn.score + cte.new_score) as new_score
   from in_tab as inn  
   join cte
   on inn.rn > cte.rn
 )    
select f.*
from cte f 
order by f.new_score
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a full cartesian?  I'd be very careful doing this, but:

```
select
*
from
(select distinct score from <yourtable>) scores
cross join (select distinct grp from <yourtable>) grps
order by grp,score
```

I can't imagine why anyone would want to do this, and I feel a little dirty suggesting this solution.